# Openstreetmap: Bring ways of motorway in the correct order

Tags: gis, openstreetmap

I want to analyze the duration of speed limits on german motorways.
Therefore I chose the relation 20904, which is a german motorway. https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/20904.
I expected that the members (way pieces) are in the correct order. That means to me, that each following way is in the next line. But there are ways which are not sorted at all. For example the last member of that relation is anywhere in the middle of the motorway.

How can I sort the members of the relation in a chronological order? I couldn't find anything about it so I think I got something really wrong in working with OSM

I tried to sort the ways in a json by identifying the last and the first node of the ways, but here again I'm not sure if the nodes are in the correct order.

Comment: What about looking the starting and and points of each component line? Relations are about putting different features, but not about ordering them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
So the nodes in a component line are ordered so that the first node is the starting point and the last node is the endpoint of that line?

Comment: In a line the nodes are ordered. In fact direction of a line is relevant in OSM. Just for roads you may consider that a relation may contains various things: the two directions may have own "road" (and same relation), Entry, exit, etc. may be also in the same relation, so you may need to discard many lines (but probably the shortest ones), and you may still get two parallel lines.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks a lot for your answers. Now I know what to do